# What is the cost (flops) of calculating the inverse of a diagonal matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra

Given a nonsingular $n\times n$ matrix A, calculating the cost of the inverse of matrix A is  approximately $2n^3/3$. I'm not sure how to proceed from there.

Comment: If the matrix is diagonal, only $n$ items to take recriprocals of.

Comment: The inverse of the diagonal matrix $\operatorname{diag}(a_1, ... a_n)$ is the diagonal matrix $\operatorname{diag}(\frac{1}{a_1},..., \frac{1}{a_n})$.

Answer (score 1):

The cost for a **diagonal** matrix is $n$ divides.  Because most algorithms (but not this nearly trivial one)  can be formulated to use a number of divides that grows more slowly than the number of multiply/add operations, a divide is conventionally counted as one flop, even though division may take longer.